# Maths for university Software Development degree

Tags: math, statistics, computer-science

I start university in September and my current tutor passed some of her maths work down. I thought I would take a look and it just looks like pure gibberish and I'm starting to get a little worried. Are there any books/courses/resources that you can reccomend for someone new to maths in computer science? My maths modules are:

- Mathematics for Software Development
- Data Structures and Algorithms
- Statistical & Computational Mathematics

Comment: This is not really a programming question, which is the purpose of Stackoverflow. It is better suited for the computer science discussions here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 2):

It depends a lot on what level of development you plan on doing.  The vast majority of software development can get by with a course on discrete mathematics (example books: [Discrete Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072899050) or [Outline of Discrete Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071615865)).  For a course like data structures and algorithms its important to have an understanding of mathematical proof's as they are used to show the correctness and running time of an algorithm.  Statistics 
is useful in many areas in understanding uncertainty, I personally really like this book: [Probability & Statistics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321500466).  If you find that it is too high level then this book may be more your speed: [Intro to Probability and Statistics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123704839). 
Finally if you plan on doing a lot of computational mathematics then a book on numerical analysis would be helpful, however you really need an understanding of linear algebra and calculus before diving into this area.  A good book on numerical analysis can be found here: [numerical analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0538733519)